# Programs/Libraries for calculating solvent excluded surface and excluded volume

Tags: software, one-topic-per-answer, software-recommendations, python

Given the 3D structure of a molecule (*e.g.* as `*.mol`) and a probe radius `r`, I want to calculate the solvent excluded surface (SES) and the excluded volume enclosed by it. Note the difference between SAS and SES:

[image]

I'm looking for a command line program, C/C++ or Python library that can accomplish such a task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### MSMS

[MSMS](http://mgl.scripps.edu/people/sanner/html/msms_man.html) is a rather old (1996) command line tool that computes the Solvent Excluded Surface (SES). It is wrapped in a python module in [mgtool](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/packages/MSMS/?searchterm=msms) or in [openstructure](https://openstructure.org/docs/1.3/bindings/msms/) which may be more convenient to use.

Comment: Includes everything I was looking for and the Python bindings is a neat plus. You set the bar very high for potential competing answers.

Comment: Nice to hear you got an answer that you like! [The other answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4544/5) is substantially longer, was that suggestion not useful for you?

Comment: I personally went for MSMS, but I will give him the bounty for his effort.

Answer (score 10):

### EDTSurf

EDTSurf[1] is a common and reasonably well regarded approach. The source code is available at https://zhanglab.ccmb.med.umich.edu/EDTSurf/

I tested the mac version and it worked with the following:

```
./EDTSurf_mac -i kras.pdb
```

which outputs `kras.ply`. A slight hiccup is the website describes different command line arguments - but the default is the SES. You'll see they have windows and linux versions, too.

Assuming you're comfortable with python, you could then visualize the output with Open3D:

```
import open3d as o3d
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("./kras.ply")
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])
```

Now, for volume. Volume of the SES is difficult to calculate exactly, but the volume of a mesh is trivial to calculate. Open3D has a `get_volume` method:

```
mesh.get_volume()
```

unfortunately that froze my jupyter notebook every time - you may have better luck with a fresh install.

But the following will also work:

```
import numpy as np

verts = np.array(mesh.vertices)
faces = np.array(mesh.triangles)

def signed_vol_of_triangle(p1, p2, p3):
    v321 = p3[0]*p2[1]*p1[2]
    v231 = p2[0]*p3[1]*p1[2]
    v312 = p3[0]*p1[1]*p2[2]
    v132 = p1[0]*p3[1]*p2[2]
    v213 = p2[0]*p1[1]*p3[2]
    v123 = p1[0]*p2[1]*p3[2]
    return (1 / 6)*(-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123)


def make_vol(pts):
    return signed_vol_of_triangle(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2])

print(sum([make_vol(v) for v in verts[faces]]))
```

In short, this loops through each triangle in the mesh and calculates the signed volume of the triangular prism with the fourth point at the origin. The theory behind this is in [2], and I used the implementation in this SO answer which you might want to also consult: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568551/3089865

While I haven't rigorously tested that volume-calculating approach for correctness, it returns `21058.959617488006` angstrom cubed, which seems reasonable to me (~21 nm^3) given KRAS fits in a ~4x3x3nm box.

[1] Xu, Dong, Hua Li, and Yang Zhang. "Protein depth calculation and the use for improving accuracy of protein fold recognition." Journal of Computational Biology 20.10 (2013): 805-816.

[2]Zhang, Cha, and Tsuhan Chen. "Efficient feature extraction for 2D/3D objects in mesh representation." Proceedings 2001 International Conference on Image Processing (Cat. No. 01CH37205). Vol. 3. IEEE, 2001.

Answer (score 3):

[Gepol93](https://web.archive.org/web/20230426191455/http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/molecular_surface/gepol93/) is a FORTRAN library which computes three kinds of envelope surfaces :

- Van Der Waals molecular surface
- Accessible molecular surface
- Solvent Excluding surface

There is also a python library called [Pychemovality](https://github.com/vandan-revanur/pychemovality) (which is authored by me) that calculates the solvent excluded surface area (SESA) in order to calculate ovality of molecules.

This python library uses a modified version of GEPOL93 under the hood. This library outputs the SESA and corresponding volume.

Also if you are interested in using the modified GEPOL93 Fortran script directly, then I have included compilation instructions for it on the pychemovality repo [here](https://github.com/vandan-revanur/pychemovality/blob/master/docs/fortran_compilation_instructions.md).